Quirks mode in WordPress template in Firefox only, works fine in Chrome
I am getting the "This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”." warning in Firefox from a WordPress site.
The site uses <!DOCTYPE html> at the very top of the template html but of course all the WordPress config, plugins etc. are loaded before that. The error is not showing in Chrome. How do I resolve this warning?
